# Частичное сравнение строк

Tags: javascript

Для частичного совпадения в строке я использую метод .includes,

```
var str = 'man';
'woman'.includes(str);//true
```

Но если в `str` будет пустая строка, то метод тоже вернёт `true`.
Нужно либо сделать так, чтобы метод `includes` возвращал `false` при пустой строке, либо искать другое решение, которое я к сожалению не нашел.

Comment: Используйте тернарный оператор, проверяющий, пуста ли строка-шаблон.

Answer (score 4):

Добавление к комментарию @[Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina)

```js
function _includes(str, fstr) {
  return (!!fstr && fstr.length) 
    ? str.includes(fstr)
    : false;
}


console.log(_includes('', 'man'));
console.log(_includes('go', 'man'));
console.log('------>', _includes('goman', 'man'));
console.log(_includes('12goma1ngo', 'man'));
console.log('------>', _includes('mango', 'man'));
console.log(_includes('null', false));
console.log(_includes('false', false));
console.log(_includes('null', null));
console.log(_includes('false', null));
console.log(_includes(null, ''));
console.log(_includes(true, null));
console.log(_includes(undefined, undefined));
console.log(_includes(undefined, []));
console.log(_includes({}, []));
console.log(_includes(NaN, []));
console.log(_includes([], NaN));
```